# Read and display csv data in table with Node (ya-csv)

Tags: node.js, csv, express, npm

I am attempting to take a standard input from a csv file and have the user upload that file. I then want to display that data in tabular form so that they may make corrections/approve the data before I write it to the database.

This is my first real foray into express and node and, despite finding many of the libraries, I am a little confused about

1) Which is the easiest to use
2) Where do the particular functions go.

I understand the router pointing to my Jade file, however I'm still a little lost about where to put custom javascript for the processing of the code.

I have started going down the ya-csv route but there isn't a good tutorial out there. Does anyone have any experience implementing this npm module?